# Else Statement Not Working

Tags: c#

```
int number = 4;
int guesscount = 0;
int guess;

Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

while (guess != number)
{
    guesscount = guesscount + 1;

    if (guess < number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low");
    }
    else if (guess > number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!!");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

When running the code the if and else if statements work but when guessing the correct number (4), the message "You got it" does not display the window just closes

Comment: Take a look at your `while` condition...if they guess the correct number, the `while` loop doesn't execute.

Comment: You also have two ReadLine in your while loop. Why?

Comment: This would be an excellent opportunity for you to learn how to use breakpoints, to step through the code, so that you can see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside the loop, `guess` is not equal to `number`.
See your condition in while operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you type in the correct number, the while loop expression is false (guess equals number) so that code block is not executed. Here's a working solution:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        int number = 4;
        int guesscount = 1;
        int guess;
        string guessMessage;

        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
        guess = GetNumber();

        while (guess != number) {

            if (guess < number) {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low");
            }
            else if (guess > number) {
                Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");
            guess = GetNumber();
            guesscount++;
        }

        if (guesscount == 1)
            guessMessage = "Well done!!! You got it first time!";
        else 
            guessMessage = "You got it!! It took " + guesscount + " guesses.";

        Console.WriteLine(guessMessage);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int GetNumber() {
        int number;

        while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) {
            Console.WriteLine("That was not a number!\nGuess again: ");
        }

        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Why not use guessCount++; ?

Comment: Yeah, I ignored the guesscount as it wasn't being used. Though the usage of guesscount would be wrong anyway. Have updated code to use it properly and get a funkier message at the end :)

Comment: Also, the Convert.ToInt32 will throw an exception if a non-numerical character is entered; have updated code to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because after the first guess, if the right number is typed, the program goes out of the loop before trying to show the messages again?

Why not trying a do while loop:

```
int number = 4;
int guesscount = 0;
int guess;

do {
    if (guesscount == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");
    } else {
        Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");
    }
    guesscount = guesscount + 1;
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();

    if (guess < number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low");
    }
    else if (guess > number)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!!");
    }
} while (guess != number)
```

Comment: also Eric's answer is right, if you enter the right number at the first attempt the condition for the while loop evaluates to false, ignoring the entire block

Comment: In your code sample, when they guess the correct number it still asks them to guess again...?

Comment: true, I missed that one, I've already fixed the code, I moved the message block inside an if statement at the beginning of the do while loop

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  You can take the "you got it" instruction outside the loop, It will run when the guess is equal to the number (that is what you are looking for).  The loop will work while you don't guess the number, so only greater than and less than are evaluated in here.  Here is a working code:

```
    int number = 4;
    int guesscount = 0;
    int guess = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Guess a number between 1 and 10: ");    
    guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    while(number != guess){
        if(guess < number)
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too low");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Your guess is too high");

        Console.WriteLine("Guess again: ");
        guesscount = guesscount + 1;
        guess = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("You got it!!!!");
```

Answer (score -3):

Errrm ..... 
Please does the "Guess again: " works?
It it works, then add Console. Readkey() after

```
 Console.WriteLine("You got it!!");
```

Comment: this should be in the comment

Comment: Adding `Console.Readkey()` after that line will not resolve the problem. The final `else` block is never hit.